# Showing contiguous events on a bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some data that represents a bunch of contiguous events. For this example it is operators of a machine over a 24 hour period:

```
StartDT              Operator    DurationSeconds
2004-02-01 22:00     Barry            6420
2004-02-01 23:47     Darren          18780
2014-02-02 05:00     Sharon          21600
2014-02-02 11:00     Gary            10800
2014-02-02 14:00     Barry           28800
```

Here is some SQL to generate the dataset:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-02-01 22:00') As StartDT,
'Barry' As Operator,
6420 as SecondsDuration
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-02-01 23:47'),
'Darren' As Operator,
18780 as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-02-02 05:00'),
'Sharon' As Operator,
21600 as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-02-02 11:00'),
'Gary' As Operator,
10800 as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-02-02 14:00'),
'Barry' As Operator,
28800 as Duration
```

I represent this on a single bar graph with different coloured bars for each operator.

I put `SUM(SecondsDuration)` in the value/data area and the bar stacks up to 24 hours. I put Operator in the Series section and order it by StartDT and do some conditional formatting and I can see the 24 hours split into operators.

This gives me the bar graph I want.

However the value axis gives me total number of seconds, i.e. from 0 to 86400 (24 hours in seconds)

Is there any way to change these labels to hourly buckets, i.e. 22:00, 23:00, 00:00, 01:00 up to 21:00

I've messed about a fair bit and I don't think it's possible.

I'll be happy with any relatively simple solution including extensions to the SQL

At the moment my workaround is to create a tablix underneath and line it all up. Not pretty.

There are some more complex aspects to this which I will put into another question.

Comment: You can get the `Time` from the `startDt` column and use it in the `Category Groups`. So the `y-axis` will be displaying the time part

Comment: But this will split it into multiple bars. I only want one bar

Comment: Is modifying the dataset an option? I would suggest this would be the place to do it. Failing that, add a calculated column to your dataset which places the second labels into your bucket labels. You can then use these bucket labels in the graph as necessary.

Comment: I'm  can modify the dataset, but the problem is that the existing data does not fall neatly into the buckets. Also I can't find any properties anywhere to override the horizontal axis labels. The thing is there is kinds of properties referring to Intervals of minutes and hours etc. but I don't think they are going to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an expression similar to the following as the Series Value to convert it to hours:

= Sum ( Fields!SecondsDuration.Value ) / 3600

Then I would set the Axis Number Format to  00':00'

Then I would set the Axis interval to 1 (if you want to see every hour).

Comment: You're on to something there. It's an excellent idea. I didn't click with me that the scale could handle fractions. What this _does_ let me do is at least format as hours rather than seconds which is excellent. The only problem is that the hours go from 22:00 past midnight to 10:00 in the morning so it has to go 22,23,00,01 etc. But perhaps I can make still make it do that somehow by offsetting it. You've given me something to think about.

Comment: Although not exactly what I was after it gave me some good ideas